# How can I run Teradata recursive query to find hierarchies in table?

Tags: sql, teradata, recursive-query

I have a table -

```
ID       Name
A        Steve
AA       Carla
AAA      Anthony
AAAA     Martin
AAB      Casey
AABA     Mark
```

In input data above

•   Employee “Steve” has ID “A”. A single character like this represents that the customer bought the product without any referral.

•   From Steve’s referral, Carla bought another product and got ID of “AA”. Here Carla’s customer code “AA” represents that he is referred by some customer with ID “A”.

•   From Carla’s referral, Anthony and Casey bought products and got ID(s) of “AAA” and “AAB” respectively, signifying that they are referred by Carla with ID “AA”.

•   Each referral’s ID has a pattern and can be translated into IDs all the way up in the chain.

I need to convert this table to following table using Teradata SQL recursive query **ONLY**

```
DATA LINEAGE
1>Steve
1.1>>Carla
1.1.1>>>Anthony
1.1.1.1>>>>Martin
1.1.2>>>Casey
1.1.2.1>>>>Marc
```

Following points are worth mentioning regarding this output:

•   Multiple referrals for a particular person are in alphabetic order. For example, Anthony & Casey are displayed in alphabetic ascending order with Anthony getting prefix of 1.1.1 while Casey getting 1.1.2.

•   There can be multiple customers who start the Chain i.e. direct customers without any referrals.

•   All direct customers should have whole numbers in the start of their output (with no dot and a single arrow).

•   Customers starting the chain i.e. direct customers should also be in alphabetic order among themselves.

•   Number of prefix symbols “>” correspond to the depth of hierarchy.

Comment: This looks like the OUTPUT from a recursive statement. It's not really a great input since the parent/child relationship is based on the position of a character in a single field. Furthermore, the need to increment based on the multiple referral suggests the need for a DENSE_RANK() window function, which isn't possible inside a recursive CTE. Why force a recursive CTE to handle this instead of something like `REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` with `XML_AGG()`, `SUBSTRING()` and `LENGTH()` to push things back together again?

Comment: **(1)** The explanations does not match the actual data (Mary, Jonathan & Koen? Mike?) **(2)** What characters are being used to construct the `ID` values in the real data (A-...) ? **(3)** **_"ONLY"_**? as opposed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't recursive, but I don't feel that it needs to be.

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE voltest
(
    id VARCHAR(50),
    nm VARCHAR(50)
) PRIMARY INDEX (id) ON COMMIT PREServe ROWS;
INSERT INTO voltest(id,nm) VALUES ('A','Steve');
INSERT INTO voltest(id,nm) VALUES ('AA','Carla');
INSERT INTO voltest(id,nm) VALUES ('AAA','Anthony');
INSERT INTO voltest(id,nm) VALUES ('AAAA','Martin');
INSERT INTO voltest(id,nm) VALUES ('AAB','Casey');
INSERT INTO voltest(id,nm) VALUES ('AABA','Mark');

SELECT
    path || bumpers || nm as "DATA LINEAGE"
FROM
(
    SELECT
        oreplace(TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM (XMLAGG(trim(id_number) || '.' ORDER BY token_index) (VARCHAR(50)))), ' ', '') as path,
        bumpers,
        nm
    FROM
        (
            SELECT to_number(token, 'xxxxx')-9 as id_number, nm, token, token_index, SUBSTRING('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>' FROM 1 FOR max(token_index) OVER (PARTITION BY nm)) as bumpers
            FROM TABLE (
                REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(voltest.nm, volTest.id, '', 'i')
                    RETURNS (nm VARCHAR(50) character set unicode, token_index integer, token varchar(50) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
                ) AS dt
        ) sub
    GROUP BY nm, bumpers
) sub2
```

That `regexp_split_to_table` will split every character in the `id` column into it's own row with nm as the key. We also capture the position in `token_index`. The split out character is captured in `token`.

We use `to_number` to spit out the integer value of the hex representation of your `token` and subtract 9. So `A`=1, `B`=2, and so on.

We use a window function `MAX()` on the `token_index` for each name to determine how many arrows `>` to pull for that name.

Then we stitch it all together with `XMLAGG` aggregating the token string with a period delimiter (trimming the last one off).

This will spit out the following:

```
+-------------------+
|   DATA LINEAGE    |
+-------------------+
| 1.1.1.1>>>>Martin |
| 1.1.1>>>Anthony   |
| 1.1.2.1>>>>Mark   |
| 1.1>>Carla        |
| 1>Steve           |
| 1.1.2>>>Casey     |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill. I'll try out this solution. Although recursion is not necessary, but I was learning SQL recursive queries and this was a puzzle given to me, hence asked for a recursive SQL. :)

Comment: You could probably do this with recursion by using `substring()` and tracking the recursive depth through the iterations. But it would get pretty ugly. Generally recursive queries work best on data that is structured `child | parent | attributes...` to produce data like `node | path>to>node | depth | attributes...` but in your case your data `path>to>node | attribute ` so it's more like the end result.